# Restart concourse single vm with bosh

Tags: concourse

I'm following the [quickstart concourse guide](http://concourse.ci/concourse-lite.html) to test CI on my project, the first time I did everything worked great:

```
$ bosh create-env concourse-lite.yml
```

Upon executing the above command I was able to go http://192.168.100.4:8080 and start using concourse, however after restarting the host machine, I'm unable to restart concourse, if I execute:

```
$ bosh create-env concourse-lite.yml
```

It verifies the dependencies but skip initializing the virtual machine.

```
Deployment manifest: '/home/javier/work/sandander-devops/concourse-ci/concourse-lite.yml'
Deployment state: '/home/javier/work/sandander-devops/concourse-ci/concourse-lite-state.json'

Started validating
  Downloading release 'concourse'... Skipped [Found in local cache] (00:00:00)
  Validating release 'concourse'... Finished (00:00:02)
  Downloading release 'garden-runc'... Skipped [Found in local cache] (00:00:00)
  Validating release 'garden-runc'... Finished (00:00:01)
  Downloading release 'bosh-virtualbox-cpi'... Skipped [Found in local cache] (00:00:00)
  Validating release 'bosh-virtualbox-cpi'... Finished (00:00:02)
  Validating cpi release... Finished (00:00:00)
  Validating deployment manifest... Finished (00:00:00)
  Downloading stemcell... Skipped [Found in local cache] (00:00:00)
  Validating stemcell... Finished (00:00:02)
Finished validating (00:00:07)
No deployment, stemcell or release changes. Skipping deploy.

Succeeded
```

I finally decide to rebuild the environment:

```
$ bosh delete-env concourse-lite.yml --state concourse-lite-state.json
$ bosh create-env concourse-lite.yml
```

And even though it's quite efficient to reinitialize the full concourse stack, including pipelines, it would be great to know if there is a better way to deal with this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bosh lite? We have constantly problems that the instances are not working when a bosh lite installation gets restarted.

If so i would recommend you to use VM snapshots for your bosh director and try to recover the state when you start your machine again.

But at the very end if you have a problem to get it running again... the best you can to is recreate everything ... :(

Comment: I'm using:

    bosh -v
    version 2.0.40-9fc1ea4-2017-09-18T23:00:15Z

I'll follow your advice about creating a snapshot, =)